# Changing subview position in uinavigationbar in iOS 10 after pushing controller

Tags: uinavigationbar, subview, uinavigationitem, ios10

My uinavigationbar has a subview. I've added at index 0. When I push some controller with animation a subview brings to top and hides navigation items, but if I push controller without animation a subview stays below items. It happens only in iOS 10. I can't understand why that.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with navigation bar subviews reordering when I pushed or popped new view controllers.

What actually did the job for me was setting the delegate on my base `UINavigationController` in it's `viewDidLoad`method and resetting the visibility on my navigation bar in `navigationController:willShow:` delegate method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    delegate = self
}


func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    guard let hidden = viewController.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden else { return }
    viewController.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = !hidden
    viewController.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = hidden

}
```

UIKit ¯_(ツ)_/¯